# App Service Deployment using azure devope pipeline

Tags: azure-app-service-envrmnt

I created an `azure app service` and trying to create a deployment for same, I selected the `azure repo >> pipeline (Preview)` option which created a building job internally and it ends up with below errors:

> error : MSB4801: The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" is not supported
>   on the .NET Core version of MSBuild. 
>       error MSB4175: The task factory "CodeTaskFactory" could not be loaded from the assembly "C:\Program
>   Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.105\Microsoft.Build.Tasks.Core.dll".

when I manually create the build pipeline with asp.net template it builds ok.

is there any way I can change the target pipeline of app service to the working one?

or how to troubleshoot above build errors? (it seems to be my project not compatible with .net core framework...)

Comment: The pipeline that works, did you create it in Azure DevOps or some other CI/CD?